# Why is the program throwing an error "cannot find symbol" at setVisible in my showPanel method?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

Why is the `setVisible` method throwing an error saying symbol not found in my `showPanel` method?
It does not make sense as I am referencing a `JPanel` stored in an `ArrayList` so it should be able to use `setVisible`.

```
public class mainFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form mainFrame
 */
private ArrayList list;
public mainFrame() {
    initComponents();
this.setSize(500,500);
    int h=this.getHeight();
    int w=this.getWidth();

    homePanel homePnl = new homePanel();
    this.add(homePnl);
    homePnl.setLocation(0,0);
    homePnl.setSize(w,h);
    homePnl.setVisible(true);

    DeploymentInfoPanel infoPanel = new DeploymentInfoPanel();
    this.add(infoPanel);
    infoPanel.setLocation(0,0);
    infoPanel.setSize(w,h);

    atomServerPanel atomPnl = new atomServerPanel();
    this.add(atomPnl);
    atomPnl.setLocation(0,0);
    atomPnl.setSize(w,h);

    autoDeploymentPanel autoPnl = new autoDeploymentPanel();
    this.add(autoPnl);
    autoPnl.setLocation(0,0);
    autoPnl.setSize(w,h);

    list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(homePnl);
    list.add(infoPanel);
    list.add(atomPnl);
    list.add(autoPnl);


    this.pack();
}

public void showPanel(int panelNum){
    list.get(1).setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Class names should begin in uppercase so they don't get confused with variable names, which start in lowercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private ArrayList list;
```

You didn't specify the type of Object that will be added to the ArrayList. So by default get() method will return an instance of Object. There is no setVisible(…) method for an `Object`

When you define the ArrayList you should be using:

```
private ArrayList<Component> list;
```

Now the compiler knows you are adding `Component` instances to the ArrayList.

In fact, the compiler will check to make sure you only add `Component`.

It will also get rid of the warning messages when you compile.

Also class names should start with an upper case character. Sometimes you do and sometimes you don't:

```
DeploymentInfoPanel infoPanel = new DeploymentInfoPanel();
...
atomServerPanel atomPnl = new atomServerPanel();
...
autoDeploymentPanel autoPnl = new autoDeploymentPanel();
```

Notice how the forum highlights properly named classes making the code easier to read?

Follow Java conventions and be consistent.

Finally, to display multiple panels in the same area of the frame you should be using a [Card Layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

Comment: So just to clarify would using card layout require a lot of revamping of my code or is it a relatively quick fix? My professor suggest that I use the arraylist strategy and within each panel we could pass in an enum value or int to show which panel we wanted displayed using getwindowsancestor to call the frame parent class and then pass through an index of the panel we wanted to display.

Comment: *we could pass in an enum value or int to show which panel we wanted displayed* - this is basically what the CardLayout does, except you use a String value to identify the panel you want to display. So you don't need to reinvent the wheel. Read the tutorial and download the demo code!